# Why is my CONTEXT_INFO() empty?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a method that sets up my linq data context. Before it returns the DC it calls a stored proc that sets up the CONTEXT_INFO value to identify the current user.

A trigger picks up any changes made and using this context data writes an audit record.

I noticed that my context data was in the audit table blank so I wrote a simple unit test to step through this process and I still get nothing. However if I paste all the Linq-To-SQL statements into a query window the context data is there.

Looking at a profiler trace it makes quite a few sp_reset_connection calls in this process. I had understood that these should not have an affect on the CONTEXT_INFO value though.

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Linq to SQL `DataContext` does not actually hold the connection open when you execute queries, either using query comprehension or `ExecuteQuery`/`ExecuteMethod` call, and `CONTEXT_INFO` only lives in the context of a single connection.

In order to get this to work, you need to manually open the connection on the `DataContext` using `context.Connection.Open()` before setting the context_info.  Once the connection is already open, successive queries won't auto-close the connection when they're finished.

Note - the technical reason for this is that it invokes `ExecuteReader` on the `IDbCommand` with `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` set, unless the connection was already open.  You can see the same behaviour yourself if you use `SqlCommand`/`IDbCommand` objects with the same flag set.

Edit - I guess I should also point out that if the connection is pooled, technically the physical connection is "open" the whole time, but the `IDbConnection` is still getting closed, which is what causes the connection resets.

Comment: This is why I love stack overflow. You've just helped me avoid a miserable weekend. Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

sp_reset_connection does reset context_info. sp_reset_connection  is the procedure called by the client app pools when recycling a connection, so it appears that you're seeting the context on one connection, closing the connection and expecting the context to be set on a new connection, whcih is obviously erroneous.